# How to pass value from one method to another without using return?

Tags: c#, string

```
Public void method1()
{
    string val="abc";
}

Public void method2()
{
    if(val=="abc")
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?
I want to get the value of "val" in method2.

Edit-

```
string[] credentials = new string[7];
public void StoreCredentials(string server, string user, string pass, string instanc, string port, string domain, string company)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(server) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(instanc) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(port)
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pass) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(company))
    {
        credentials[0] = server;
        credentials[1] = user;
        credentials[2] = pass;
        credentials[3] = instanc;
        credentials[4] = port;
        credentials[5] = domain;
        credentials[6] = company;
    }
    else
    {
        credentials = null;
    }
}

public bool SaveCredentials()
{
    if(credentials==null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the code in which I am working on.

Whenever i call the method  `SaveCredentials()` from another class, the `string[] credentials = new string[7];` gets initialized every time, overwriting the values I stored earlier.

Comment: Make it global variable, i.e class field/variable.

Comment: You can use a private variable to share state of object between methods.

Comment: I done that.. let me edit the question.

Comment: Yes, that's called an instance variable or property.

Comment: The duplicate question provides me the solution with returning the value. I don't want to use the return.

Comment: If you had read the answers, they have multiple ways of getting the strings, some use return, some a property and others use a static variable. Feel free to use what suits your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are they in the same class? If so, you could have a class variable/property like this:

```
public string Val {get; private set;}
public void method1()
{
    Val ="abc";
}

public void method2()
{
    if(Val =="abc") {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

Though be careful, you need to make val has been set before you start using it.

**EDIT**

After reading your update, the reason it is being reset elsewhere is because you're most likely creating a new instance of the class storing the variable. For example, if this was a `Credentials` class and you call it once using this:

```
Credentials c1 = new Credentials();
c.method1();
```

But then later on, you have a different class need to access it, you accidently call:

```
Credentials c2 = new Credentials();
c.method2();
```

This `c2` is now a new instance of the the `Credentials` class and won't have ever had `method1()` ran. You need to pass around the instance of `c1` to where you need it and then you can call `method2()` safely.

**EDIT 2**

Another option is to use the singleton pattern, if there should only ever be one instance of this class and you always want to access it, you could do the following:

```
public class Credentials {
    private static Credentials instance;

    private Credentials() {}

    public static Credentials getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Credentials();
        return instance;
    }

    public string Val {get; private set;}

    public void method1()
    {
        Val ="abc";
    }

    public void method2()
    {
        if(Val =="abc") {
            Console.WriteLine(Val);
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Val is not set");
        }
    }
}
```

[An example dotNetFiddle can be found here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bTkied)

Comment: yes. I am calling from two different class. Method1() form one and method2() from another.

Comment: The methods are in the same class though? If the settings should be the same, you shouldn't be creating a new instance of the class, instead pass the initial object created to where it should be used. Your other choice is to use the singleton method. Will there only ever exist one object of this class for each runtime of the application?

Comment: Take a look at the project https://github.com/devdrone/NAVWSUi

Comment: Afraid not, unless I'm getting paid. I've provided plenty of information on how you could now solve the problem. Look at the dotNetFiddle, it should make it clear how these different methods work